# How can I write a RegEx that only allows certain characters?

Tags: regex, coldfusion

I'm writing a small script (similar to SO's tag RegEx) that only allows the following characters: `[a-z 0-9 + # - .]` But I can't figure out the right syntax:

I've come up with this:

`ReReplace(myString, "[A-Z]", "", "ALL")` which removes capital letters. I'm not sure how to include the special characters in the expression, however.

The [ReReplace()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7e98.html) I'm using is a ColdFusion function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`[^a-z0-9+#\-.]` should work. The `^` symbol within the `[]` means "Everything that's not in this list".

I'm not 100% on ColdFusion and if you'll need to escape the `#` but if you find any issues, just escape the other special characters.

Comment: @JonathonBolster I'm not familiar with any regex implementation in which `+` or `.` have special meaning inside a character class. Your backslashes (while harmless) can and probably should be removed. _(The `-` (hyphen), on the other hand, does need to either be escaped or placed as the last character in the class.)_

Comment: @Phrogz - yeah, I realised about the `-` when I posted. I couldn't quite work out the `+` and `.` though so thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Jonathan, it works fantastically well! You do need to escape the #. The first version you posted did not work, but this one does! Cheers!

Comment: PS: Is there a way to re-write this to remove any numbers at the beginning of the string?

Comment: @Mel - I am not sure if you do it all in one expression. If not, `"^[0-9]+"` would find one or more numbers at the beginning of a string.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks for that! On a final note, I would like to allow a comma, but adding it to the RegEx doesn't seem to work... do I have to do anything special for that?

Comment: @JonathonBolster- You also need to escape single quotes ('). But thanks this helped me a lot.